# How to delete an object from an ArrayList Map in Firestore using Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.chatRoomDeleteTimer = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
        return db.collection("ChatRoom").where('timestamp', '<', Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000) - 60).get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                const promises = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

                promises.push(doc.ref.delete());
                db.collection("UsersFilter").doc(doc.get("chatRoomLeader.userID")).update({"UsersInChat": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({"age": doc.get("chatRoomGuest.age"), "chatRoomID": doc.get("chatRoomGuest.chatRoomID"), "cityName": doc.get("chatRoomGuest.cityName"), "email":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.email"), "km":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.km"), "name":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.name"), "profilePic":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.profilePic"), "timestamp":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.timestamp"), "userID":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.userID")})});

                });
                return Promise.all(promises);
            });
    });
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. The first part works where I delete all the chatRooms that are 1 minute old, however when I try to use FieldArray remove for some reason that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Changed this:

```
db.collection("UsersFilter").doc(doc.get("chatRoomLeader.userID")).update({"UsersInChat": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({"age": doc.get("chatRoomGuest.age"), "chatRoomID": doc.get("chatRoomGuest.chatRoomID"), "cityName": doc.get("chatRoomGuest.cityName"), "email":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.email"), "km":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.km"), "name":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.name"), "profilePic":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.profilePic"), "timestamp":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.timestamp"), "userID":doc.get("chatRoomGuest.userID")})});
```

To this:

```
db.collection("UsersFilter").doc(doc.data().chatRoomLeader.userID).update({"UsersInChat" : admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({"age": doc.data().chatRoomGuest.age, "chatRoomID": doc.data().chatRoomGuest.chatRoomID, "cityName": doc.data().chatRoomGuest.cityName, "email": doc.data().chatRoomGuest.email, "km": doc.data().chatRoomGuest.km, "name": doc.data().chatRoomGuest.name, "profilePic": doc.data().chatRoomGuest.profilePic, "timestamp": doc.data().chatRoomGuest.timestamp, "userID": doc.data().chatRoomGuest.userID})});
```